# execute bat passing variables from php

Tags: php

I've a bat file (test.bat) that I execute with php exec in this way

```
$bat_file= 'c:\test.bat';
$output = null;
exec($bat_file, $output);
```

test.bat

```
echo hallo %1 %2
```

I'd like to pass 2 variables to the bat file with php exec command, it's possible to do it?

```
example: test.bat $var1 $var2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

```
$bat_file = "C:\test.bat ".escapeshellarg($var1)." ".escapeshellarg($var2);
```

[Docs](http://php.net/escapeshellarg)

Comment: 'C:\test.bat '.$var1.' '.$var2; I tried this way and it works just the same. thanks

Comment: `escapeshellarg` makes sure that you will always have two arguments, regardless of the argument contents. For instance, what if one of them has a space?

Comment: If I tried with "C:\test.bat ".escapeshellarg($var1)." ".escapeshellarg($var2); the script does not run. I must write with single '  $bat_file = 'C:\test.bat ' and if I use escapeshellarg my result is hallo "john" "doe" instead of hallo john doe